# IIS funciona apenas no localhost

Tags: windows, iis, amazon-aws

Estou usando IIS em um Windows Server 2012 R2, pela AWS Amazon EC2.
Mas estou com um problema, consigo acessar o site apenas no localhost.
Quando tenta acessar de outra maquina pelo IP, retorna o seguinte erro:

```
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

Segui os passos de alguns videos no Youtube, apenas instalei o IIS, como mostrava o video. O que pode estar acontecendo?

Comment: acho falta configurar firewall..

Comment: tentei desabilitar firewall mas nao funcionou

Comment: desabilitar firewall é diferente de configurar firewall

Comment: ok, então como eu configuro?

Comment: normalmente vc vai nas configurações.. rsrs

Comment: sim mas oq é configurar? liberar portas? quais? como faço?

Comment: vc tentou fazer algo ou está só perguntando, esperando uma mega resposta?  Mão na mssa filhote!

Comment: tentei sim, tentei varios tutorials... mas nada resolveu. por isso to perguntando, oq devo configurar?

Comment: Dê uma lida sobre Security Groups no AWS. É bem possível que sua instância no EC2 não esteja permitindo acesso a partir da Internet. Você pode precisar criar um Security Group abrindo acesso às portas 80 e/ou 443 para acessar seu IIS.

Comment: @sergiopereira muito obrigado, problema resolvido! pode postar como resposta que irei marcar

Comment: @Thiago. Resposta postada. Valeu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dê uma lida sobre Security Groups no AWS. É bem possível que sua instância no EC2 não esteja permitindo acesso a partir da Internet. Você pode precisar criar um Security Group abrindo acesso às portas 80 e/ou 443 para acessar seu IIS.